# Cross Browser Awesome looking Box Shadow Effect

Tags: javascript, css

Does anyone know a script or a place where i can find a Fancy CSS Box Shadow effect which looks like the following:

http://www.red-team-design.com/how-to-create-slick-effects-with-css3-box-shadow

But that also works in IE7+ ?

Thank you for your help :)

Sebastian

Comment: This may help : http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable CSS 3 Box Shadows, Border Radius for IE, you can use, [CSS 3 Progressive Internet Explorer](http://css3pie.com/) plugin.

#### From their [website](http://css3pie.com/):

> PIE makes Internet Explorer 6-9 capable of rendering several of the most useful CSS3 decoration features.

Comment: Thank you!, i have used the simple(stock) Box shadow technique using PIE, will i be able to create the attached shadow effect which is a bit more advanced using PIE?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. Just keep in mind about the performance too.